# Typescript - My method variable seems to coerce to string when it should throw an error

Tags: typescript

I have the following line of code

```
this._LayoutDiv.style.borderRight = this.BorderLineWidth + "px";
```

but "this.BorderLineWidth" is actually a method defined like

```
BorderLineWidth(): number {
    return this._BorderLineWidth;
}
```

So i'd like this line to throw an error. Why is TypeScript allowing this method to coerce to string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used the + operator to concatenate the value to a string TypeScript automatically converted to the string primitive type.

You can see a table of behaviour in section "4.15.2 The + operator" of the language specification.

If an argument on either side of a + is a string, the result will be a string:

```
var result = true + 'string';
```

Or

```
var result = 'string' + 1;
```